# how to upgrade psych version >=2.0

Tags: ios, macos, rubygems, cocoapods

**YAML safe loading is not available. Please upgrade psych to a version that supports safe loading (>= 2.0).**

[image]

In order to install cocoapods , when Operating a gem sources - l instruction in terminal,it had this question.

Answer (score 0):

i have this problem too.

gem version greater than Rudy

you can update you Rudy version.

`$ rvm list known`

`$ rvm install xxx`

`$ rvm use x.x.x --default` change your ruby version